# Is it possible to create a public ip with specific IP address?

Tags: azure, azure-public-ip

For some reason we need to use a specific IP, let's say, 123.456.789.112

Is it possible to create a public IP with this IP address 123.456.789.112?

Comment: It is not possible for anybody anywhere ever to have IPv4 address 123.456.789.112 because 456 and 789 are not (decimal representations of) valid octet values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible with public IPs.

There are governing bodies that distribute IP addresses on a global scale, and Azure only gets a small set, compared to the entire global usage, of IP addresses it can use.

You can read more [here](https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/ip-addresses-beginners-guide-04mar11-en.pdf)